# Detect intent-filter received by app

Tags: android

I'm building an app that is registered for the intent filters IMAGE_CAPTURE (Camera) & PICK (Gallery).

For the Activity, how do I detect which intent filter was received?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In onReceive

```
String action = intent.getAction();
```

and use this to compare with the action you register for.